# Enhance Vanialla JS function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object with properties. These properties may or may not exist.

So that I can access properties, I work as follows:

```
myData.properties.find(p => p.name == 'target').value = 'Foo';
```

Now it can happen that `myData` does not have the property with the name `target` at all.
Therefore I would like to extend the `Array.prototype.find()` function to create the missing element.

```
Array.prototype.findOrCreate()
```

It's supposed to be usable later:

```
myData.properties.findOrCreate(p => p.name == 'target', { name: 'target', value: '' });
```

However, I don't know how to approach the function.

I'm not looking for the solution here (I even ask that nobody provides the solution here), but the necessary theory as I implemented it.

In PHP I would look at the function definition and extend it. However, I can't find the function definition of [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to extend the array prototype (as this can lead to conflicts and forward compatibility issues). Instead, you can create a separate function which performs this with an array as input. You can use `.find()` with the conditional (`?`) operator to default the value if `.find()` returns `undefined`:

```js
const findOrCreate = (arr, f, def) => {
  const res = arr.find(f);
  return res === undefined ? def : res;
}

const data = [{name: 'foo', value: 1}, {name: 'bar', value: 1}];
const obj = findOrCreate(data, p => p.name === 'xyz', { name: 'target', value: '' });
console.log(obj);
```

Or, if you're supporting ES2020, you can use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) (`??`) like so:

```js
const findOrCreate = (arr, f, def) => arr.find(f) ?? def;

const data = [{name: 'foo', value: 1}, {name: 'bar', value: 1}];
const obj = findOrCreate(data, p => p.name === 'xyz', { name: 'target', value: '' });
console.log(obj); // {name: "target", value: ""}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a new function to `Array.prototype`. `find()` is a simple loop, arrays have no other indexing magic, it has to iterate over the array and either stumble upon a suitable element or not.

```js
var a=[{name:"something",value:1},{name:"somethingelse",value:2}];

Array.prototype.findOrCreate=function(name){
  for(var elem of this)
    if(elem.name === name)
      return elem;
  var newelem={name:name};
  this.push(newelem);
  return newelem;
}

console.log("original",JSON.stringify(a));
a.findOrCreate("something").value=3;
console.log("modified",JSON.stringify(a));
a.findOrCreate("somethingbrandnew").value=4;
console.log("extended",JSON.stringify(a));
```

Note that you could rather use a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for storing key-value pairs (or even a simple object).

Answer (score 0):

Where you can definitely can extends Vanilla JS Objects, this practice is generally to consider bad, since it can leads to [conflicts](https://esdiscuss.org/topic/having-a-non-enumerable-array-prototype-contains-may-not-be-web-compatible) and issues on [compatibility](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1443630).

Also, in this case, since you want to find an item with name `target` in an array, and if there isn't, create a new ones, I would have more atomic functions. Those action are clearly separated to me, and put them in one method is not good practice either – as atomic functions they're easily composable.

In your case the code is simple:

```
let target = myData.properties.find(p => p.name == 'target') || {name: "target"};

target.value = "Foo";
```

If you also want to add this new object to the `properties` array:

```
let target = myData.properties.find(p => p.name == 'target');

if (!target) {
  target = {name: "target"};
  myData.properties.push(target);
}

target.value = "Foo";
```

But, if you really, really, really want to extends the native array:

```
Array.prototype.findOrCreate = function findOrCreate(predicate, item) {
  let target = this.find(predicate);
  if (!target) {
    this.push(item);
    return item;
  }
  return target;
}

myData.properties.findOrCreate(p => p.name == 'target', {name: "target"}).value = "Foo";
```

However it would be probably more secure having as function:

```
function findOrCreate (array, predicate, item) {
  let target = array.find(predicate);
  if (!target) {
    array.push(item);
    return item;
  }
  return target;
}

findOrCreate(myData.properties, p => p.name == 'target', {name: "target"}).value = "Foo";
```

Because you won't clash (you could also avoid clashing using [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) but then you have to toss it around in your code every time you want to access to that method).

As more atomic functions you could have:

```
find(myData.properties, item => item.name == "target")
  .or(create({name  : "target"}))
  .value = "Foo";
```

The implementation of that approach could be something like:

```
function find(array, predicate) {
    const item = array.find(predicate);

  return {
    or(action) {
        return item || action(array);   
    }
  }
}

const create = (item) => (array) => (array.push(item), item);
```

But, if you really prefers an OOP approach, I would strongly suggest to extends `Array` in your own class:

```
class MyArray extends Array {
    constructor(...items) {
      super(...items);
     }

    findOrCreate(predicate, item) {
      let target = this.find(predicate);

      if (!target) {
        this.push(item);
        return item;
      }
      return target;
   }
}
```

At this point you can use all the array's method, plus yours. And you can convert from regular arrays to yours as well – if you can't create them directly, for example you got that from an external API:

```
myData.properties = MyArray.from(myData.properties);
```

If you got from JSON string, you could also use a custom `reviver` to use the your class instead of the native array, during the [parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).